# How Should I refocus camera on an object while editing?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, edit-mode

I am just a beginner in Blender, When I am editing an object on the plane, the 3D Viewport is not showing the accurate direction and path, due to which I am unable to do editing easily on that object. I tried to focus the camera on the viewport, but it wasn't helpful.How should I correct the angle of the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but you can always center your view to a specific object, face, vertex, ... by selecting it and pressing <kbd>,</kbd> on your NumPad.

The view now orbits around that point.

If you want to aim your active camera to the same view, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>

To look around you, hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>